# s-t cut algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I'm looking for an implementation of s-t cut algorithm for flow network (directed graph) in Python.

Is there vertex cut version of the algorithm?

Comment: Have you checked http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[igraph](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-igraph) has it:

```
>>> from igraph import Graph
>>> from random import randint
>>> g = Graph.GRG(100, 0.2)        # generate a geometric random graph
>>> g.es["capacity"] = [randint(0, 1000) for i in xrange(g.ecount())]
>>> cut = g.maxflow(0, 99, "capacity")
```

`cut.membership` then gives you the membership of each vertex (0-1 vector), `cut[0]` gives you the vertices on one side of the cut, `cut[1]` gives the other, `cut.value` gives the value of the cut.

Comment: Any way to get the vertex cut set? Other than the trivial answer of end points of edge cut-set. Can we find the minimum vertex cut-set too?